# Is it possible to save the wounded Batarian in the refugee camp?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the mission "Citadel: Wounded Batarian", you encounter and speak with, well, a wounded Batarian named Ghorek. The guy's pretty beat up and only has a "50/50" change at survival. You talk to him a bit and then are given the decision to put the fella' down quickly or let him suffer awhile. Neither of these choices seemed particularly good.

**So I'm wondering, is there a third, non-obvious way to proceed?** Is there an obscured path in game that allows you to aid the Batarian and restore him to health? If so, what rewards does that route yield? Also, does it affect any further story threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the only options are to kill him quickly or let him die slowly. Confirmed by the offical Prima guide for the game and also the [Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Wounded_Batarian).

It's just a short little mission with a nonconsequential character, so unlike the "big" deaths there's no side path that lets you save hin.

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly he was labeled as a traitor, directly responsable for the attack on the Citadel. So my honest guess is saving him would kind of defeat the purpose of bringing justice to persons responsible for the attack... which would make Sheppard a bad guy/girl. So I think there is no way to cure him.

I'm not sure about the attack on the citadel but he is a terrorist : http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Wounded_Batarian

Killing him is the paragon option, leaving him to die the renegade option. Saving him is nonexistant.